# Add portlets to Plone front page

Tags: plone, portlet

I TRY to manage content on a Plone-based website, www.capital-tennis.org.  I know ALMOST NOTHING about Plone itself.

I want to add 2 portlets to the front page (main page) of the website, one on the left (in the white blank space) and one on the right (to the right of the leagues/tournaments links).  The new portlet on the left should mirror the 4 externally visible events in the EVENTS folder at the top of the front page, basically acting as a repeater to bring attention to those events on the front page.  These 4 events on the front page should be in thumbnail view.  The new portlet on the right should be an external link to a website.

I don't exactly know what kind of permissions I have.  I know I can delete and add content to other pages.  I assume I can do the same with the front page.

I don't know if I have to use the portlet management tools on the website or if I can write the HTML code to reverse engineer the creation of these 2 portlets.

When you reply, please treat me as an idiot, stepping me through every button press, etc.  I would REALLY, REALLY appreciate your help.

Eric

Comment: I'd say that the frontpage template is explicitly constructed to switch of portlets; all other pages have a login portlet. By the looks of things, you have a Plone 3 site, you'd need to edit the template that creates the frontpage to re-enable portlets.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: +1 for checking it's a Plone-3.

Comment: @user2208236: What happens, if you call 'http://www.capital-tennis.org/front-page/manage'? If you get 'permission denied' or s.th. similar, you have to get in touch with the site-administration.

Answer (score 3):

If you have full admin rights you should see *Manage portlets* link somewhere on the front page after login.

[image: Manage portlets]

Here you can add

- Event portlets which automatically pulls published events on the site
- Static text portlet where you can enter text and links with WYSIWYG editor

[image]

No need to program. No need to even write HTML.

Please check if you can get this done and if it looks you get there then ask additional information, if needed, in the question comments and I can retrofit the answer.

Comment: Plone 3 uses new style portlets and mechanism is the same. Are you sure you are not confusing with Plone 2, @MartijnPieters?